why touch pad randomly freezes after upgrade to ubuntu 24.04.1?
Since upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04.1 from 22.04 my DEll inspiron laptop touch pad randomly freezes requiring a reboot to work again; I have 4 GB of RAM but a very light user; the upgrade was complicated by the fact that installer froze and I was force to quit it; I then made a full upgrade using terminal and changed the desktop icon extension which wasn't working; has anyone experienced something similar?

Eventually after repeated updates the freezing problem seems to have been fixed; sadly I cannot tell what was bugging my laptop so my answer won't be much help to others; I was about to post a log when it got fixed
